# Query string not being added to api unless click search twice in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

My query string is being generated correctly, but doesn't get added to the api unless I click the search button twice. After the initial first click, the search works fine each time. Unless I reload the page. Same is true if using a different input for the search.

As you can see in the console. The input data is defined in the search form.

First click..

```
SearchForm.js:26 IDXT001 2222
API.js:8 The query string is undefined
```

Second Click..

```
API.js:8 The query string is filter=IDXT001|2222
```

Is this a issue with timing? Seems stange that it works fine after each subsequent click.

Api..

```
search: function(query) {
console.log("The query string is " + query)
return axios.get("http://api/document?" + query );
},
```

Method..

```
 loadContracts = (query) => {
  API.search(query)
  .then(res => {
    const contracts = res.data;
    this.setState({ contracts })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Submit button..

```
 handleFormSubmit = event => {
event.preventDefault();

const formData = this.state.formValues
let keys = Object.keys(formData);

keys.map(k => {
  let query = '';
  if (query !== "")
  query += `&`;
  query += `filter=`
  query += `${k}|${formData[k]}`

  this.setState({query}) ; 
  return this.loadContracts(this.state.query);
})
};
```

**EDIT**
Does not work fine each time after first click. If I change the data value after first click, the previous value get added to the api. So this is definitely a timing issue. My guess is that the query string is being added to the state after first click and then sent to the api on next click. So I need to change the code to have the query string be directly added to the loadcontracts function or have a .then before after sending to state and then return loadContracts()?

Comment: From the looks of things your code is going to initiate a new query for every key in the formData object. Could you log out what these keys are for the first and second handleFormSubmit calls?

Comment: @Marcus are you asking for a log of keys? keys is the id of the input ["IDXT001"].

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the loadContracts = (query) method above the handleFormSubmit. So since react is top-down, the query string was stuck in the state on the first click and wasn't being added to the loadContracts = (query) until the second click. That's how I'm seeing it anyways. Correct me if I'm wrong.